# CREATE VIEW changes CURRENT_SCHEMA

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create a view in a different schema from the one I am currently connected to.

Currently I am connected to the **main** schema in the **my_db** database. There is a table **source_table** on the **main** schema. I want to create a view in the **my_db.other_schema**, over the **main.source_table**.

How come the following SQL command works (creating a table):

```
create or replace table my_db.other_schema.my_view as
    SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

and this one doesn't (creating a view):

```
create or replace view my_db.other_schema.my_view as
    SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

However, if I specify the database/schema in the inner SELECT when creating a view, it works (I can't do it though, because of templating reasons in my code - the query that generates the view only has objects with unspecified schema/database and relies on the connection parameters):

```
create or replace view my_db.other_schema.my_view as
    SELECT * FROM my_db.main.source_table;
```

I have noticed that the CREATE VIEW statement changes the CURRENT_SCHEMA(). Is there any way to disable this behavior? See for example:

```
create temporary table my_db.other_schema.test_table as
select current_schema() as c;

select * from my_db.other_schema.test_table; -- shows MAIN

create temporary view my_db.other_schema.test_view as
select current_schema() as c;

select * from my_db.other_schema.test_view; -- shows OTHER_SCHEMA
```

Finally, if it's not possible to solve this problem, is there an issue in creating a view on the MAIN schema first, and then creating a second view on the other schema with `SELECT * FROM MAIN.VIEW`? I am afraid that creating a view from another might raise unexpected errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is documented right here :
[CREATE VIEW Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html)

> When a view is created, unqualified references to tables and other database objects are resolved in the view’s schema, not in the session’s current schema. Similarly, objects that are partially qualified (i.e. schema.object) are resolved in the view’s database, not in the session’s current database.

So your following query will fail as there's no table/view named *source_table* in *my_db.other_schema*

```
create or replace view my_db.other_schema.my_view as
SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

So two solutions :

1/ Use fully qualified references

```
create or replace view my_db.other_schema.my_view as
SELECT * FROM my_db.other_schema.source_table;
```

2/ Place yourself in the target schema if it also contains the data for the view

```
 USE schema my_db.other_schema;
 create or replace view my_view as
 SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

There's no problem to create a VIEW relying on another one as long as your create them in the right order regarding their dependencies.

Comment: Thanks so much! I looked in the documentation, but missed that detail.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is as intended and it is described in documentation.

[View - Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html#usage-notes)

> **When a view is created, unqualified references to tables and other database objects are resolved in the view’s schema, not in the session’s current schema.** Similarly, objects that are partially qualified (i.e. schema.object) are resolved in the view’s database, not in the session’s current database.
>
> The SEARCH_PATH session parameter (if present) is ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed that detail in the docs.